Knight Rider type movie but was about a motorbike not a car
I've been told what the the name of this movie, many times but for some reason I have a mental blockage in remembering its name.
The movie was very similar concept to Knight Rider, advanced vehicle, except the good guy was riding a motorbike not driving a car. The main character would dress up all in black the bike also was black, and it had gadgetry like the Knight Rider car. The rider had a home base from which he communicated etc with.
That's unfortunately all I remember about it.

Street Hawk. But its a tv show though. is this the one youre talking about?  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCItnKrXvMM

Warrior of the Lost World had a talking motorcycle and made for a great episode of MST3k.

Cyclone, movie about a female character who's boyfriend/husband dies after he makes this 5 million dollar bike.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092812/

Welcome to Movies & TV! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.
